# Python - Task Scheduler 0x1

Tags: python, excel, csv, scheduled-tasks

Having a frustrating time with scheduling a Python script (C:\Python27\test.py), which has the following code:

```
import xlrd
import csv
with xlrd.open_workbook('Z:/somefile.xls') as wb:
        sh = wb.sheet_by_index(3)
        with open('Z:/somefile.csv', 'wb') as f:
                c = csv.writer(f)
                for r in range(sh.nrows):
                    c.writerow(sh.row_values(r))
```

This script is supposed to take worksheet 3 in "somefile.xls" and save it into it's own .csv file. When I run it manually from the Python Shell, it works as intended.

Z:\ is a mapped drive located on an entirely different server.

When I try to run from the Task Scheduler, I keep getting the 0x1 result code. I have the Task set up as the following:

- Run whether user is logged on or not - Do Not Store Password
- Run with highest privileges
- Program/script: python.exe
- Add arguments (optional): "test.py"
- Start in (optional): C:\Python27

I've read quite a few posts, all with different suggestions, none of which worked.

Anyone else run into this situation before?

Jeff

Comment: You're specifying the full path to your python executable, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ran into this a few weeks ago, Task Scheduler can be a real pain!

For whatever reason, I have never been able to get a script to run when the "Run whether user is logged on or not" option is selected.  I spent something like 10 hours on the phone with my IT department trying  to figure it out.  It can't be done.  Un-checking that option should then allow your script to run.

Comment: Task scheduler is beyond a pain now haha! Just to confirm, you selected "run only when user is logged in", correct?

Comment: @user3473345, correct.  I also don't have "Run with highest priveleges" selected, not sure if that will have any impact

Comment: I unselected "Run whether user is logged on or not" option and selected "run only when user is logged in". I ran the task and still got the (0x1) error code unfortunately.

Comment: Unselected the "Run with highest privileges", and it worked!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same problem, maybe you can try the following configuration:

- Program/script: C:\Python27\python.exe (Full path of the program executable)
- Add arguments (optional): test.py (Name of the file to run)
- Start in (optional): C:\Python27  (Full path of the folder where the file is)

This configuration works for me. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried all the way above but didn't work.

My configuration (like this):

- Program/script: `python.exe`
- Add arguments (optional): `D:\test.py`
- Start in (optional): `C:\Python37\`

Finally, I make out that I read the file in my python script

```
pd.read_excel("./xlsx/XXX.xlsx")
```

I thought it will direct to "`D:/xlsx/XXX.xlsx`" but it didn't. I changed the code in my script:

```
pd.read_excel("D:/xlsx/XXX.xlsx")
```

and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem:
But problem was because path had a space between words.
"C:/python/pythonw.exe" "E:\python\Sales prog\sales prog111.py"
I did:
"C:/python/pythonw.exe" "E:\python\Salesprog\salesprog111.py"

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issues when trying to run as another user privileges.
I finally logged in to server with "another user" account and find out that python modules for that user were missing.

I ran the .py script with that user with command line and installed all the missing modules with pip for that user.

Then everything started working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone running into this problem who is using a **virtual environment**:

1. Go to `your_project_folder\your_venv\Scripts` and find `python.exe`.
2. Copy its full path
3. Use this as the executable for the "Program/Script" option in Task Scheduler (NOT the standard Python install location which you might have found with `where python` for instance)

This will use the Python instance that contains all your packages to run your code instead of the globally installed version of Python, which may or may not contain them. As a result, it should prevent errors caused by missing packages which can be a common cause of the `(0x1)` error.

An alternative solution would be to install all of your required packages globally on your machine, though in general, this isn't a great practice.

**NOTE**: There can be other causes of the `(0x1)` error, such as if you have bugs in your code, but if all is smooth there and you couldn't get your script to run from the Task Scheduler, this should solve it for you.

Hope this helps!